# System does not poweroff - how to diagnose

Tags: systemd, shutdown, acpi

After upgrading to debian jessie my **dated desktop system** no longer powers off reliably (/sbin/poweroff - via systemctl on tty1). Instead, it shuts down, pauses and reboots and only powers off if I press the power-button. I tried various recommendations like `acpi=force` playing with bios settings, adding nouveau.modeset=0 and many more.

The only thing I found so far, is that not starting a graphical session seems to "fix" the problem. My Xsession is a simple `.xsession` file, there is no session manager involved (afaik) and all I do is start a number of programs. When I strip this file down to just an `xterm` or I do not log in at all, the system powers down.

I tried to uncomment more programs in my .xsession file in the hope of finding a culprit, but this did not lead to a conclusion. There seems to be some randomness involved. I am sure than none of my programs are still runnig at the time I issue the poweroff because I kill them all (uncluding a user systemd which was started by I-dont-know-who)

In the last messages before it reboots I see

```
System wakeup enabled by ACPI
Preparing to enter systel sleep state 5
GPU lockup - switching to software fbcon
```

But I see the same messages when it *does* poweroff (not 100% sure, because they are visible only for a short moment then)

Also I notice that in the bad cases, there are long pauses in the shutdown process, e.g. after `Stopping target network` there is like a 2-minute pause and I don't know what the system is waiting for.

What I am after is a way *to diagnose* the problem, rather than shooting at the moon.

- How can I find out what the system is waiting for in those long pauses
- Or more generally: how can I get more information about what's going on during shutdown, is there a "shutdown log"?
- How is acpi involved in the shutdown process and how can I find out why it is doing what it is doing?

Comment: Trick to read messages only visible for a short while (other than a serial console, which is hard if your laptop doesn't have serial ports—and I'm sure it doesn't): use a cell phone (etc.) camera to take a video of the screen. Then you can pause the video to read messages that are only there for a fraction of a second.

Comment: Have you tried the steps described in the section "Diagnosing Shutdown Problems" in [Debugging systemd](https://freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/Debugging/)?

Comment: Some Intel chipsets (IvyBridge/Haswell or about that time) had a quirky USB3 XHCI controller: if the XHCI controller was not shut down properly, it would cause the system to restart after power-down. The quirk even was subtly different in various versions of the chipset, so pinning down the required shutdown procedure in each case was quite tricky. [See bug #66171 in Linux kernel bugzilla.](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=66171)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue on two different systems, albeit with Wheezy.

The solutions were different:

### Solution 1

Blacklisting the kernel module `mei_me` (Intel Management Engine) fixed the issue on one machine.

### Solution 2

On another machine it was a pm-utils issue, try to write `on` to `/sys/bus/*/devices/*/power/control` and shutdown.

Source: https://askubuntu.com/questions/132882/why-do-i-get-a-reboot-instead-of-a-shutdown

Comment: INTEL_MEI is set to "No" in my kernel config. And I don't have any "control" files in  /sys/bus/*/devices/*/power/.  I don't think this is it.